# how to create a table with checkboxes using razor + bootstrap

Tags: razor

In a mvc application i need to show a list of strings as checkboxes. i want to create a table with 4 columns.

the code:

```
@{ int i = 0; }
@foreach (string s in Model)
{
    if (i % 4 == 0)
    {
        @Html.Raw("<div class=\"row\"><!--row-->");
    }
    @Html.Raw("<div class=\"col-sm-3\">")
    @Html.CheckBox(s)
    @Html.Label(s)
    @Html.Raw("</div")
    if (i % 4 == 3)
    {
        @Html.Raw("</div><!--close row-->");
    }
    i++;
}
```

for some reason that i dont understand this code write a div class=col-sm-3 only when a row is written, each 4 items. It should write a column for each string but it does'nt .

Comment: Why are you using `Html.Raw` like that?  It's completely unnecessary.  See any MVC tutorial.

Comment: the problem was missing >.in @Html.Raw("</div"),